# How does stackoverflow format textarea when click edit button?

Tags: javascript, html, richtextbox, frontend, wmd

**This is not a duplicate question, i know how to create a rich editor, but i meet problems**

I want to make a rich text box like stackoverflow does.

1. I import the wmd plugin just like SO.
2. When i **save** a topic to mysql, it saves the processed text like this:

> < p>hello world< /p>
>
> < pre >< code >class Text {} < /code >< /pre >

This is normal i think because the html page can render this correctly.

But When i try to edit this topic, **it directly shows the code in my textarea**:

[image]

**What i need is this(Just like the first time i entered):**

[image]

My textarea code is very simple like this:

```
<!-- text area start -->
      <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
      <textarea id="wmd-input" name="description" onblur="checkForm()">${topic?.description}</textarea>
      <div id="wmd-preview"></div>
<!-- text area end -->
```

Anyone can help ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us the code what you have tried with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a rich text editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007242/how-to-create-a-rich-text-editor)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, i know how to create a rich editor, here i want to know why i meet this problem.

Comment: You see what you see because that's what you saved. SO doesn't do anything magic, it just takes your text and persists it as-is.

Comment: You must not have something interpreting the HTML tags when loading it into the textarea from the database. While you may have a rich text editor in place for when you create from the textarea, without having it interpret existing input onload: it won't format that text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the answer myself.

What i need to do is simply add a new hidden field to store the **original text** before **wmd** process it.

And then i save both original and processed text into my database.

When i need to edit it, just use original text.
When i need to render it, use the processed text.

Comment: I sure would like to see the sample code there as to how you did that. the entry form , wmd? -- whatever that is and also the  datatable,  Do you have a brief sample of that and where I can get this wmd ?